# Issues saving foreign key in Hibernate one-to-one relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following one-to-one Hibernate relationship:

**USER**

```
@Entity
@Table(name=User.TABLE_NAME)
public class User {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="hibernate-uuid", strategy="uuid2")
    @Column(name="id", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Login login;

    @Column(name="firstName", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName", nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name="startDate", nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name="expirationDate", nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private Date expirationDate;

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE
}
```

**LOGIN**

```
@Entity
@Table(name=Login.TABLE_NAME)
public class Login {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "login";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="hibernate-uuid", strategy="uuid2")
    @Column(name="id", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private String id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password", nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name="passwordHash", nullable=false)
    private String passwordHash;

    @Column(name="token")
    private String token;

    @Column(name="tokenExpirationDate")
    private Date tokenExpirationDate;

    @Column(name="lastLogin")
    private Date lastLogin;   

 // GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE
}
```

**USER DTO**

```
public class UserDTO {
    private LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();

    @Override
    public  User to(User user) {
        user.setFirstName(this.getFirstname());
        user.setLastName(this.getLastname()); 
        loginDTO.setEmail(this.getEmail());
        Login login = loginDTO.to(new Login()); 
        user.setLogin(login); 
        user.setStartDate(this.getStartDate());
        user.setExpirationDate(this.getExpirationDate());
        user.setLogicallyDeleted(this.getLogicallyDeleted()); 
        return company;
    }

    @Override
    public void from(User user) {
        this.setFirstname(user.getFirstName());
        this.setLastname(user.getLastName());
        this.setEmail(user.getLogin().getEmail());
    }

    public LoginDTO getLoginDTO() {
        return loginDTO;
    }

    public void setLoginDTO(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
        this.loginDTO = loginDTO;
    }

}
```

**LOGIN DTO**

```
public class LoginDTO {
    private String email;

    public void from(Login login) {
        this.setEmail(login.getEmail());
    }

    public Login to(Login login) {
        login.setEmail(this.getEmail()); 
        return login;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**REST CONTROLLER**

*I use Spring Data so Service and Repository classes are excluded in this post because they are self explanatory*

```
@RestController
public class CompanyController extends UserController{

    private static final String  PATH_CREATE_USER = "/user/save"; 

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(PATH_CREATE_USER)
    public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody CompanyDTO dto) {
        User user= dto.to(new User());
        user.getLogin().setPassword(dto.getPassword());

        // Password as text for testing purposes.
        user.getLogin().setPasswordHash("haasssshhhhh"); 
        userService.save(company);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**I post the following data from Postman:**

```
{
    "firstname": "ben",
    "lastname": "moore",
    "email": "example@mail.com",
    "password": "pass",
    "startDate":"2018-06-20T00:00:00",
    "expirationDate": "2018-10-20T00:00:00"
}
```

The results I get is that all the columns in the `user` table get saved as expected. The columns in the `login` table all get saved except the `user` column that is left empty. I am expecting the `user` column in the `login` table to be filled with the primary-key of the `user` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just haven't set both of the reciprocal references between the user and the login.

In your data transfer objects, I see you setting the login on the user but I don't see where you are setting the user on the login.

```java
user.setLogin(login);
```

I think you need

```java
login.setUser(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you save the password in clear text?

```
    user.getLogin().setPassword(dto.getPassword());
    user.getLogin().setPasswordHash("haasssshhhhh");
```

Not nice.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Login login;
```

This says that the `Login` entity is the owner of the relationship. That means that only the `Login` entity will persist the relationship. I don't see anywhere in the code where you set the `user` field of the `Login` entity.

Comment: The User entity can persist the relationship because the cascade=CascadeType.ALL means that when saving User, it must also save Login. You don't have to save Login separately that is the meaning of the One-To-One relationship. Your second point of setting User of Login is correct as also suggested by "Philip Wrage". After setting the user on Login in the UserDTO, it works as expected without saving Login separately

Comment: "You don't have to save Login separately that is the meaning of the One-To-One relationship." -- no, that is the meaning of the cascade option.